# Jquery default dropdown value and save changes in datatables for download

Tags: jquery, datatables

Working on a table that allows you to selct rows, change one of the columns, and then download the data...

Problem 1:
I have a dropdown that appears in one column when a row is selected. The dropdown displays all of the unique options for that column. The problem is, it's defaulting to the first option alphabetically when it is created. I want it to default to the orignal value in that cell.

Problem 2:
If you select a row, and then change the dropdown value to something else, it isn't captured anywhere. I need the selected value to be the new value for that cell.

The desired functionality would be that a user could select a series of rows, change the dropdown to what they wanted for each row, and then download that using the download selected button.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/crashvector/f1q8w2d5/17/

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/datatables.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.0/css/select.dataTables.min.css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css" media="screen" />
<script charset="utf8" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.0/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<script charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.flash.min.js"></script>
<script charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.6/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <table id="samples" class="display nowrap compact hover dt-left" width="100%"></table>
    </table>
    </form>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="JS/datatables2.js"></script>
</body>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready( function () {    
var srcData = [
    {
        "ID": "1",
        "Name": "01_p11017",
        "Region": "GoM",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "2",
        "Name": "02_p21017",
        "Region": "GoM",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "3",
        "Name": "03_p31017",
        "Region": "GoM",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "4",
        "Name": "04_p41017",
        "Region": "GoM",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "5",
        "Name": "05_p11117",
        "Region": "GoM",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "6",
        "Name": "06_p21117",
        "Region": "GoM",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "7",
        "Name": "07_p31117",
        "Region": "GoM",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "8",
        "Name": "08_p41117",
        "Region": "GoM",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "9",
        "Name": "09_p11217",
        "Region": "GoM",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "10",
        "Name": "1-1m",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "11",
        "Name": "1-1s",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "12",
        "Name": "1-2m rep",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "13",
        "Name": "1-2s",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "14",
        "Name": "1.epa_r5_s16",
        "Region": "R5",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "15",
        "Name": "10_p21217",
        "Region": "GoM",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "16",
        "Name": "11_p31217",
        "Region": "GoM",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "49",
        "Name": "3.s18",
        "Region": "R5",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "50",
        "Name": "30_ms-horse-combo",
        "Region": "GoM",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "51",
        "Name": "31_ms-cow-b-combo",
        "Region": "GoM",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "52",
        "Name": "32_11vt-170829-r01",
        "Region": "R1",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "53",
        "Name": "33_12vt-170829-r01",
        "Region": "R1",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "54",
        "Name": "34_13vt-170829-r01",
        "Region": "R1",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "55",
        "Name": "4.epa_r5_s19",
        "Region": "R5",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "56",
        "Name": "5.epa_r5_s20",
        "Region": "R5",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "57",
        "Name": "6.epa_r5_s21",
        "Region": "R5",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "58",
        "Name": "7-d",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "59",
        "Name": "7391-1",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "60",
        "Name": "7391-2",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "61",
        "Name": "7391-3",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "62",
        "Name": "7391-4",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "63",
        "Name": "7396-1",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "64",
        "Name": "7396-2",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "65",
        "Name": "7396-3",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "66",
        "Name": "7396-4",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "67",
        "Name": "7401-1",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "68",
        "Name": "7401-2",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "69",
        "Name": "7401-3",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "70",
        "Name": "7401-4",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "71",
        "Name": "7406-1",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "72",
        "Name": "7406-2",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "73",
        "Name": "7406-3",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "74",
        "Name": "7406-4",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "75",
        "Name": "7411-1",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "76",
        "Name": "7411-2",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "77",
        "Name": "7411-3",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "78",
        "Name": "7411-4",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "79",
        "Name": "7416-2",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "80",
        "Name": "7416-3",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "81",
        "Name": "7416-4",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "82",
        "Name": "8-sf",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "83",
        "Name": "9-sb",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "84",
        "Name": "ac_8-14-17",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "85",
        "Name": "ac_8-21-17",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "86",
        "Name": "ac_8-28-17",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "87",
        "Name": "ac_9-5-17",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "88",
        "Name": "ad_8-14-17",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "89",
        "Name": "ad_8-21-17",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "90",
        "Name": "ad_8-28-17",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "91",
        "Name": "ad_9-5-17",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "92",
        "Name": "b01",
        "Region": "R5",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "93",
        "Name": "b0517",
        "Region": "GoM",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "94",
        "Name": "bg",
        "Region": "R4",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "95",
        "Name": "blank",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "96",
        "Name": "buffalo_sac_fox",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "97",
        "Name": "buffalo_santee",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "98",
        "Name": "calves_bottlefed_santee",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "99",
        "Name": "calve_scours_disease_santee",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "100",
        "Name": "canadian_goose_pierson",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "101",
        "Name": "canadian_goose_quivera",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "102",
        "Name": "canadian_goose_wyco",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "103",
        "Name": "cdh_bouy",
        "Region": "LBL",
        "Class": "background",
        "Category": "marine",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "104",
        "Name": "copy of b01",
        "Region": "LBL",
        "Class": "background",
        "Category": "blank",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "105",
        "Name": "copy of b0517",
        "Region": "LBL",
        "Class": "background",
        "Category": "blank",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "106",
        "Name": "copy of ws-1a",
        "Region": "LBL",
        "Class": "background",
        "Category": "blank",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "107",
        "Name": "cover_bc.10_8-24-12",
        "Region": "LBL",
        "Class": "background",
        "Category": "fresh",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "108",
        "Name": "cover_bl.14_8-24-12",
        "Region": "LBL",
        "Class": "background",
        "Category": "blank",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "109",
        "Name": "cover_coc.10_8-16-12",
        "Region": "LBL",
        "Class": "background",
        "Category": "fresh",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "110",
        "Name": "cover_crc.14_8-24-12",
        "Region": "LBL",
        "Class": "background",
        "Category": "fresh",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "111",
        "Name": "cover_fc.10_8-24-12",
        "Region": "LBL",
        "Class": "background",
        "Category": "fresh",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "112",
        "Name": "cover_fc.11_8-16-12",
        "Region": "LBL",
        "Class": "background",
        "Category": "fresh",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "113",
        "Name": "cover_gc.10_8-16-12",
        "Region": "LBL",
        "Class": "background",
        "Category": "fresh",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "114",
        "Name": "cover_ic.14_8-16-12",
        "Region": "LBL",
        "Class": "background",
        "Category": "fresh",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "115",
        "Name": "cover_lac.12_8-16-12",
        "Region": "LBL",
        "Class": "background",
        "Category": "fresh",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "116",
        "Name": "cover_lac.14_8-24-12",
        "Region": "LBL",
        "Class": "background",
        "Category": "fresh",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "117",
        "Name": "cover_mc.14_8-24-12",
        "Region": "LBL",
        "Class": "background",
        "Category": "fresh",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "118",
        "Name": "cover_pac.11_8-17-12",
        "Region": "LBL",
        "Class": "background",
        "Category": "fresh",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "119",
        "Name": "cover_pic.10_8-24-12",
        "Region": "LBL",
        "Class": "background",
        "Category": "fresh",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "120",
        "Name": "cover_vbc.10_8-24-12",
        "Region": "LBL",
        "Class": "background",
        "Category": "fresh",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "121",
        "Name": "cover_vbc.12_8-17-12",
        "Region": "LBL",
        "Class": "background",
        "Category": "fresh",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "122",
        "Name": "cover_wc.14_8-17-12",
        "Region": "LBL",
        "Class": "background",
        "Category": "fresh",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    },
    {
        "ID": "123",
        "Name": "cow1_santee",
        "Region": "R7",
        "Class": "unknown",
        "Category": "unknown",
        "QC_flag": "0",
        "QC_comment": "\r"
    }
];
    var dataTable = $('#samples').DataTable({
    'processing': true,
    'serverSide': false,
    'pageLength': -1,
    'lengthMenu': [
      [100, 250, 500, -1],
      [100, 250, 500, 'All']
    ],
    data: srcData,
    //ajax: {
      //url: 'http://groot.r07.epa.gov/json2.php',
      // url: './datatables.php',
      //dataSrc: ''
    //},
    columns: [
      {
        data: '',
        defaultContent: '0',
        visible: false
      },
      {
        data: '',
        defaultContent: '',
        orderable: false,
        className: 'select-checkbox',
        targets: 1,
        orderData: [0]
      },
      {
        title: 'ID',
        'className': 'dt-left',
        'visible': false,
        data: 'ID'
      },
      {
        title: 'Name',
        'className': 'dt-left',
        data: 'Name'
      },
      {
        title: 'Region/Program',
        'className': 'dt-left',
        data: 'Region'
      },
      {
        title: 'Class',
        'className': 'dt-left',
        data: 'Class'
      },
      {
        title: 'Category',
        'className': 'dt-left',
        data: 'Category'
      },
      {
        title: 'QC Concerns',
        'className': 'dt-left',
        data: 'QC_comment'
      }
    ],
    select: {
      style: 'multi',
    },
    order: ([
      [4, 'asc'],
      [5, 'asc'],
      [3, 'asc']
    ]),
    orderFixed: [0, 'desc'],
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [{
      extend: 'csv',
      fieldBoundary: '',
      text: '<span class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></span> Download (ALL) or (SELECTED)',
      exportOptions: {
        columns: [6, 3],
        modifier: {
          search: 'applied',
          order: 'applied'
        }
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Use Selected Library',
      action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
        alert('This buton needs to pass the Sample Name and Category columns to php.');
      }

    },
    {
      text: 'Upload Predefined Library',
      action: function (e, dt, node, conf) {
        alert('This button needs to allow a csv file to be uploaded and passed to php.');
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Select Default Library 1',
      action: function (e, dt, node, conf) {
        alert('This button will automatically check all rows that match predefined list 1 using the hidden ID column.');
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Select Default Library 2',
      action: function (e, dt, node, conf) {
        alert('This button will automatically check all rows that match predefined list 2 using the hidden ID column.');
      }
    }
    ]
  });

  //grab all the unique sorted data entries from the necessary row
  var category = dataTable.column(6).data().unique().sort();

  //Drop down menu stop event propagation
  $('#samples').on('click', 'tbody td select',
    event => event.stopPropagation());

  //Write dropdown value into table
  var writeCell = dropdown => {
    var currentRow = dataTable.row(dropdown.closest('tr'));
    var rowData = currentRow.data();
    rowData.category = dropdown.val();
    currentRow.remove();
    dataTable.row.add(rowData).draw();
  };

  dataTable.on('select', function (e, dt, type) {
    if (type === 'row') {
      var row = dataTable.row(dt);
      $(row.node()).find('td:eq(4)').html(
        '<select>' + category.reduce((options, item) =>
          options += `<option value="${item}" ${
            item == row.data().category ? 'selected' : ''}>${
            item}</option>`, '') + '</select>'
      );
      toggleDataAndDraw(row, type, '1');
    }
  });

  dataTable.on('deselect', function (e, dt, type) {
    if (type === 'row') {
      var row = dataTable.row(dt);
      writeCell($(row.node()).find('select'));
      toggleDataAndDraw(row, type, '0');
    }
  });

  var toggleDataAndDraw = (row, type, dataVal) => {
    if (type === 'row') {
      dataTable.cell({
        row: row.index(),
        column: 0
      }).data(dataVal);
      dataTable.draw();
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: I'm glad you eventually made use of my code, though it's not very nice of you to not accept the answers that helped you to progress from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55145299/accessing-database-to-create-list-with-pre-populated-dropdown-or-custom-option-p

Comment: I was finally able to figure out what the main issue was yesterday and haven't been able to get back to the other threads to update them and Mark an answer. (The drop-down box category variable was being created before the ajax load was completed.)  I have asked you some follow up questions on each of my threads though.   Hopefully I'll have some time this week to get back to them!  @yevgen gorbunkov

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov The thread you linked was not one you had commented on, but I have posted an update and accepted your answer on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55228782/jquery-datatables-edit-cell-in-place-with-drop-down-select/55239920?noredirect=1#comment97468157_55239920)